# Using BottomSheetBehavior to show fragments

Tags: android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I'm trying to use the BottomSheetBehavior from [Material](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/). The problem is that it is not well described and no enough examples of it are available.
[One](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066) example on Meduim, but it only shows the basics and very simple implementation.

What I exactly need is something like the one from Material [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1mYYvVz_dCIx0bRyY_VV4hOs9709f1ESb%2Fmodal-behavior-dismissal-close.mp4). But instead of clicking on the menu item to show the BottomSheet, I want to show it when user selects an item from `RecyclerView`. Also the peek height should show only the first element in the BottomSheet layout until the user pulls it up.

How to get this approach? Are there any useful example?

Answer (score 0):

Make the bottom sheet hidden when you start your activity or fragment by calling `bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)`.

And in your adapter's onClick, make the bottom sheet visible, by calling `bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED)`